# Very small jsfidlle of DOM leak with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, memory-leaks

I'm starting to track some memory leak I've got in my web game. I've found a recurring pattern that's leaking DOM nodes, but I can't figure out why. I'm not an expert at using chrome's dev tools but I'm learning.

The smallest example I could set up is this:

```
<div id = "main">
</div>

<button onclick ='reset();'> test </button>

<script>
function reset()
{
    var Div = "<select></select>";
    $("#main").html(Div);
}
</script>
```

[JSFIDDLE LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/LevefsaL/)

In chrome, when I use the dev Tools and use the timeline, we can see that:

- we got X DOM nodes when loading the jsfiddle page
- if we use the 'test' button once, we got X+2 nodes
- each subsequent use adds 3 nodes

These nodes never get GC'ed and I can't understand why. The issue is worse when you use `<option>` inside the `<select>` (that seem coherent with the fact that the parent node doesn't get GC'ed). The issue is also the same with `<input>` as far as I can see (with checkbox & radio at least).

It seems so simple that I'm obviously missing something easy, but what is it is beyond me.

Do you have any ideas how could I solve this? I've tried to use the heap snapshot, but since I'm not fully understanding it yet, I've gotten no results.

Edit : Edit to bump the question since I haven't found an answer as of yet.

Comment: inside the presented jsfiddle example ... I can only observe 1 select element no matter how many times I press the button

Comment: @noobed You need to use dev tools to see that the nodes in memory are increasing each click.

Comment: could you provide a screenshot?

Comment: @noobed http://i.imgur.com/PHf8H8w.png. The green line on the line graph shows number of nodes. It increases with every button click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also recently come across this issue using Chrome 43. It appears to be a bug in chrome itself and is fixed in Chrome 46 ([Chrome Canary](https://www.google.com.au/chrome/browser/canary.html))

Answer (score 1):

This generates elements in the deatached DOM tree - better explanation [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-chrome-developer-tools/TTVmU-WnqTw) .
This elements are C++ objects and not js ones.[image]

I agree that nodes are being created  on each click but as soon as I force GB with the approriate button, one could observe it plummeting.

Comment: Forcing the GC doesnt seem to have any effect on the node created in my fiddle portion, It mostly affects nodes of the main fiddle page (not my code). To see this, just run it a couple of times of you will see that the smallest number of node will always increase by 3 for evey click on the test button you have done. You cannot recover them.

Comment: have you looked @ http://addyosmani.com/blog/taming-the-unicorn-easing-javascript-memory-profiling-in-devtools/ ? This article is as full as it can get regarding debugging and using the dev tools. @mydi

Comment: I still have the page opened in my browser :) I read it tiwce, I think I undertand the basics but can't find how to apply what I read in my case. I'm missing a piece of the puzzle. I tried by 3 snapshot technique but can't find any htmlnode hanging around between  the 2 first steps.

Comment: it's a interesting question.. one might open a bounty in a few hours.